# How does DNS caching work on Windows and Unix-like systems?

Tags: caching, dns

I have a problem with understanding how does DNS caching work (client-side). Suppose that we have flushed DNS cache everywhere (system, browsers) and now we want to access google.com using Chrome. I imagine that this would go like this:

- Chrome checks if google.com is a valid IP address (it is not)
- Chrome checks if there is such type A (or AAAA) record in its own DNS cache (there is not one)

And on Unix-like systems, from what I know, there is no OS-level DNS caching by default, unless [nscd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd) is running - suppose it is turned on. And then, for both system:

- Chrome looks for appropriate DNS record in OS DNS cache (there is not one)
- Chrome asks OS resolver to resolve this and receives type A record
- this record is stored in both OS and Chrome DNS cache as long as its TTL is greater than 0 (browser might ignore TTL value, though)
- if Firefox wants to open google.com now, it will find the record in OS DNS cache (and save it to its own DNS cache)

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: DNS caching is usually a network stack concern.. not sure why Chrome would be involved with more than requesting an IP from a name, or why FF would behave differently.

Comment: @user2864740 browsers do store DNS cache. In fact, any application can do it. I'd like to know how it works in details. Firefox, for example:  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration

Comment: Any application is free to do DNS queries itself (and browsers are notorious to do so, even more so now with DNS over TLS and especially DNS over HTTPS) and hence cache them internally any way they want, or they ask the OS to resolve names on their behalf. The OS can then itself have a local recursive nameserver (either like systemd resolved, or an unbound server, etc.) which will do caching themselves, or the OS uses an external nameserver (either the ISP ones or some public ones like Google, CloudFlare, Quad9, etc.), which itself has a cache.

Comment: Your understanding is mostly correct, but your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.